# Programmatic configuration for Great Expectations

Tags: pyspark, great-expectations

I'm looking into integrating a validation framework to an existing PySpark project. There are a lot of examples how to configure Great Expectations using JSON/YAML files in [official documentation](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/). However, in my case table schemas are defined as Python classes and I'm aiming to keep the validation definitions in these classes.

When playing around, I noticed this kind of pattern can be used to validate single expectations without any config files:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(x=1, y="foo"),
    Row(x=2, y=None),
])
ds = SparkDFDataset(df)

expectation: ExpectationValidationResult = ds.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null("y")
print(expectation.success)
```

where `expectation.success` is either `False` or `True`. However, I'm aiming to build expectation suites and generating reports using programmatic configuration but can't find any references how to do it. This is what I tried to hack but it leads to a runtime exception:

```
ds.append_expectation(ExpectationConfiguration(
    expectation_type="expect_column_values_to_not_be_null",
    kwargs={'column': 'y', 'result_format': 'BASIC'},
))
engine = SparkDFExecutionEngine(
    force_reuse_spark_context=True,
)
validator = Validator(
    execution_engine=engine,
    expectation_suite=ds.get_expectation_suite(),
)
res = validator.validate()
```

Any pointers on how to configure Great Expectations without config files (or minimal files) are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batches are required for validating expectation suites. Here is a working example:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(x=1, y="foo"),
    Row(x=2, y=None),
])

engine = SparkDFExecutionEngine(
    force_reuse_spark_context=True,
)
validator = Validator(
    execution_engine=engine,
    expectation_suite=ExpectationSuite(
        expectation_suite_name="my_suite",
        expectations=[
            ExpectationConfiguration(
                expectation_type="expect_column_values_to_not_be_null",
                kwargs={"column": "y", "result_format": "BASIC"},
            ),
            ExpectationConfiguration(
                expectation_type="expect_column_values_to_not_be_null",
                kwargs={"column": "x", "result_format": "BASIC"},
            )
        ]
    ),
    batches=[
        Batch(
            data=df,
            batch_definition=BatchDefinition(
                datasource_name="foo",
                data_connector_name="foo",
                data_asset_name="foo",
                batch_identifiers=IDDict(ge_batch_id=str(uuid.uuid1())),
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
res = validator.validate()
```

Comment: `import` statements should always be part of code snippets IMO...